# Why wasn't Estarossa affected by Grayroad's Commandment of Pacifism when he killed Meliodas?

Tags: plot-explanation, seven-deadly-sins

In *Seven Deadly Sins* (*Nanatsu no Taizai*) **episode 14** "Master of the Sun", we find out that even the **10 Commandments can be affected by their own (or other members') commandments,** as Galand is turned to stone for breaking his word with Escanor.

In **episode 19** "Meliodas vs The Ten Commandments", **Estarossa kills Meliodas** in front of the other 9 commandments, including Grayroad. But in **episode 23** "The Hero Rises!", we find out that **Grayroad's Pacifism Commandment causes anyone killing in his presence to "lose their remaining time".**

In **episode 22** "Return of the Sins", we find out about Meliodas's curse. Is the fact that technically **Meliodas cannot die what saved Estarossa from Grayroad's Commandment**, or is there something more to it?

Answer (score 2):

All commandments are immune to the effect of other commandments except their own

> Handpicked by the Demon King himself, each member possesses a
>   Commandment「戒禁 Kaigon」, a unique power gifted to them by the Demon
>   King, which delivers a unique curse to whomever breaks a rule specific
>   to each member. This power is absolute; it cannot be opposed even by
>   its wielder, **although members of the Ten Commandments are immune to
>   all other Commandments except for their own**. The curses will only be
>   lifted if the victim defeats its wielder or at the victim's death.

Source - https://nanatsu-no-taizai.fandom.com/wiki/Ten_Commandments